# Как обратится к элементу из кода?

Tags: wpf, c++-cli

Создаю Canvas

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Canvas x:Name="GraphCanvas" Background="Azure" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="261,244,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
</Grid>
```

Пытаюсь обратится и..

```
void App::OnLaunched(Windows::ApplicationModel::Activation::LaunchActivatedEventArgs^ e) {
    GraphCanvas->...
...
}
```

И ничего, как мне отрисовать что-то там?

Comment: В WPF вы «рисуете» не в code-behind, а путём добавления дочерних элементов. Добавьте что-нибудь внутрь, оно и отрисуется, само.

Comment: Разобрались с проблемой?

Comment: Я решил что буду рисовать картинку, а не в Canvas